# How to move react event handlers to separate file ,export and then import for reuse in multiple different functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React functional component which prints a counter number being incremented or decremented on button clicks..Below is my function

I am using react version :  ^16.13.1

```
export default function  Counter(){
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const increment = () => {
        //more logic here ..
        setCount(count + 1);
    }
    const decrement = () => {
        //more logic here ..
        setCount(count !== 0 ? count - 1 : 0);
    }
    return (
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={() => increment()}>Increment SO</button>
          <button onClick={() => decrement()}>Decrement SO</button>
        </div>
      );
}
```

I want to separate event handlers logic that includes setting state in to a separate file and export it..  like below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Increment = () => {
    //more logic here ..
    setCount(count + 1);
}
const Decrement = () => {
    //more logic here ..
    setCount(count !== 0 ? count - 1 : 0);
}


export default { Increment, Decrement };
```

I wanted to use these exported functions in the Counter function like below

```
import CounterHelper from './CounterHelper';
<button onClick={() => CounterHelper.Increment()}>Increment SO</button>
```

I have run in to several error's while running this ,so i am sure i am missing some thing fundamental here. Can somebody please tell me if this is possible at all ? are there any alternate options to achieve the above said with functional component and react hooks only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass the variable references.

CounterHelper.js

```
export const Increment = (count, setCount) => {
    //more logic here ..
    setCount(count + 1);
};

export const Decrement = (count, setCount) => {
    //more logic here ..
    setCount(count !== 0 ? count - 1 : 0);
};
```

Counter.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Increment, Decrement } from './CounterHelper';
export default function  Counter(){
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={() => Increment(count, setCount )}>Increment SO</button>
          <button onClick={() => Decrement(count, setCount)}>Decrement SO</button>
        </div>
      );
}
```

**Update:**

**Using a custom hook.**

useCounterState.js

```
export default function useCounterState() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    setCount(count !== 0 ? count - 1 : 0);
  };

  return {count, increment, decrement}
}
```

Counter.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useCounterState from './useCounterState';
export default function  Counter(){
    const { count, increment, decrement } = useCounterState();

    return (
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={() => increment()}>Increment SO</button>
          <button onClick={() => decrement()}>Decrement SO</button>
        </div>
      );
}
```